# SQLAlchemy: update and select with skip locked

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to recreate the following SQL in SQLAlchemy. So far I haven't been able to get the same results.

```
UPDATE link lk
SET updated_at = NOW()
FROM (SELECT lk.*
      FROM link lk
      ORDER BY lk.updated_at
      LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED) AS row
WHERE lk.id = row.id
RETURNING row.*
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't actually lock the row and prevent it from being taken by another process.

```
with Conn.begin() as s:
    link = (
        s.query(Link)
        .order_by(Link.updated_at.desc())
        .with_for_update(skip_locked=True)
        .first()
    )
    link.crawled_at = datetime.utcnow()
    s.commit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the performed SQL with the activation of the trace through `log_statement = 'all'`.

You'll see that Sqlalchemy performs the following queries (edited for brevity)

```
LOG:  statement: BEGIN
LOG:  statement: SELECT link.id AS link_id, link.updated_at AS link_updated_at, link.crawled_at AS link_crawled_at 
    FROM link ORDER BY link.updated_at DESC 
     LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED
LOG:  statement: UPDATE link SET crawled_at='2023-03-21T12:22:34.748324'::timestamp WHERE link.id = 2
LOG:  statement: COMMIT
```

So as you can see the `SELECT` *locks* the first row (with `FOR UPDATE`) and skips the eventually locked rows (with `SKIP LOCKED`)

The following `UPDATE` changes the selected row and `COMMIT` resets the lock.

So I see no problem (despite of the *not using the prepared statement* in the `update`).

Anyway I'll rethink this approach. It seems that you try to *simulate* some *queuing system* with parallel sessions fetching exclusively rows from a table.

This is a task for dedicated *queuing systems* and not event for *plain SQL*. Using ORM (sqlalchemy) seems to be failed decision.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sounds like it should work. I am indeed using it as part of a queuing system.